# SPARQL query is not returning the required result

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, triplestore

Two JenaTDB database/Graph/Datasets are created. One with small data and one with large data. The small database has RDF data as below and large database has a large number of copies of the same above RDF data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dcat="http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#"
  xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
>
  <dcat:Dataset rdf:about="https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="urn:uuid:8a311c18-3060-438e-a8c7-9e37bcde6529"/>
    <dct:description>Demographic statistics broken down by zip code</dct:description>    
        <dcat:keyword>area</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>boundary</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>code</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>community</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>demographic</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>demography</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>development</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>district</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>lifelong-learning</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>statistic</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>youth</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>zip</dcat:keyword>    
        <dcat:keyword>zip-code</dcat:keyword>    
    <foaf:homepage rdf:resource="https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9"/>
    <rdfs:label>demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9</rdfs:label>
    <dct:identifier>demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9</dct:identifier>
    <dct:title>Demographic Statistics By Zip Code</dct:title>    
        <dcat:distribution>
            <dcat:Distribution>
                <dcat:accessURL rdf:resource="https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"/>                    
                    <dct:format>
                        <dct:IMT>
                            <rdf:value>CSV</rdf:value>
                            <rdfs:label>CSV</rdfs:label>
                        </dct:IMT>
                    </dct:format>                    
               <dct:title>Comma Separated Values File</dct:title>
            </dcat:Distribution>
        </dcat:distribution>    
        <dcat:distribution>
            <dcat:Distribution>
                <dcat:accessURL rdf:resource="https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.rdf?accessType=DOWNLOAD"/>                    
                    <dct:format>
                        <dct:IMT>
                            <rdf:value>RDF</rdf:value>
                            <rdfs:label>RDF</rdfs:label>
                        </dct:IMT>
                    </dct:format>                    
               <dct:title>RDF File</dct:title>
            </dcat:Distribution>
        </dcat:distribution>    
        <dcat:distribution>
            <dcat:Distribution>
                <dcat:accessURL rdf:resource="https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD"/>                    
                    <dct:format>
                        <dct:IMT>
                            <rdf:value>JSON</rdf:value>
                            <rdfs:label>JSON</rdfs:label>
                        </dct:IMT>
                    </dct:format>                    
               <dct:title>JSON File</dct:title>
            </dcat:Distribution>
        </dcat:distribution>    
        <dcat:distribution>
            <dcat:Distribution>
                <dcat:accessURL rdf:resource="https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD"/>                    
                    <dct:format>
                        <dct:IMT>
                            <rdf:value>XML</rdf:value>
                            <rdfs:label>XML</rdfs:label>
                        </dct:IMT>
                    </dct:format>                    
               <dct:title>XML File</dct:title>
            </dcat:Distribution>
        </dcat:distribution>    
    <dct:contributor>
      <rdf:Description>
        <foaf:name>&lt;Nobody&gt;</foaf:name>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dct:contributor>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>publisher</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>data.cityofnewyork.us</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>accessLevel</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>public</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>catalog_describedBy</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/catalog.json</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_source_id</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>50104281-92a3-4534-9d38-141bc82276c5</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>catalog_@context</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/catalog.jsonld</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>issued</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>2013-06-26</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>resource-type</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>Dataset</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>modified</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>2017-09-22</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_source_title</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>NYC JSON</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>source_schema_version</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>1.1</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>source_datajson_identifier</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>True</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>theme</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>[u&#39;City Government&#39;]</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>catalog_@id</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://data.cityofnewyork.us/data.json</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>   
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>catalog_conformsTo</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>identifier</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>landingPage</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>https://data.cityofnewyork.us/d/kku6-nxdu</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_object_id</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>55c7ec00-93f3-467a-bf97-cfa1d28d2510</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>source_hash</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>5ed3df91fa8c531bd164646dce3281d6ccd08d09</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_object_id</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>55c7ec00-93f3-467a-bf97-cfa1d28d2510</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_source_id</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>50104281-92a3-4534-9d38-141bc82276c5</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
        <dct:relation>
          <rdf:Description>
            <rdfs:label>harvest_source_title</rdfs:label>
            <rdf:value>NYC JSON</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dct:relation>    
  </dcat:Dataset>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to fetch all the triples against `dct:identifier` predicate by using the below SPARQL query.

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT ?object
WHERE { 
        ?subject dct:identifier "demographic-statistics-by-zip-code-acfc9".
        ?subject ?predicate ?object.
}
```

The problem is that SPARQL query is working fine on the small database but is not working on the large database. Any suggestion what is going wrong?

**EIDT**
By not working I mean in case of JenaTDB the query is keep executing for hours.

Comment: Are you querying the correct TDB instance? What means "not working"? Are you 100% sure that the larger dataset contains data matching your query?

Comment: Yeah I am sure the larger dataset contains the matchind data. And TDB instance is correct.

Comment: How large is your dataset? How many memory did you allocate to TDB?
 What happens if you append `LIMIT 10`?

Comment: The large dataset is 28M triples and appending `LIMIT 10` has no effect. The problem is that memory and processor consumption remains constant during all those hours. On the other hand Virtuoso returns empty result.

Comment: 28M is rather small. I cannot believe that this takes ages even on a small machine. Can you share the dataset?

Comment: Regarding Virtuoso: That means either your query doesn't match any data or you set the parameter `MaxQueryExecutionTime` in your `virtuoso.ini` file. This means it returns all results found in the specified time, also know as  *anytime* feature

Comment: In virtuoso I have increased `MaxQueryExecutionTime` so the first comment of no data maching could be the case but I have verfied the data exists in the datastore. I will share the dataset shortly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158773/discussion-between-jamal-and-aksw).

Comment: As posted, this question is not about Virtuoso, so I'm removing that tag. If you want to address the Virtuoso-tangent from the comments, please ask a fresh question, either here on SO or on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/). I strongly suggest you shift from RDF/XML to Turtle, at least for your examples and testing, as this is much easier for human efforts.